# Webfonts not working when code looks to be correct

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm making a new site and webfonts aren't working at all. I stole the chunk of code as well as the same exact font files from a previous website I made, yet they don't work on this new site. I'm working from a responsive framework so I have a feeling something is taking priority over the code I've written to use webfonts.

The URL is http://willryan.us/responsive and the chunk I'm (currently) trying to make a webfont is the big "Will Ryan" at the top.

loading font

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'MuseoSlab700';
  src: url('assets/webfonts/museo_slab_700-webfont.eot') format('eot'), 
       url('assets/webfonts/museo_slab_700-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('assets/webfonts/museo_slab_700-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  /* font-weight:200; /* fixes bold bug in Firefox */
  /*-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* Fixes viewing in Safari. Maybe unnecessary */
  }
```

header code

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family:  'MuseoSlab700', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight : normal;
margin-top: 10px;
letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

specific header code

```
h2 { 
font-family: 'MuseoSlab700';
color: #222;
margin-bottom : .5em;
margin-top : .5em;
font-size : 2.75em; /* 40 / 16 */
line-height : 1.2;
text-align: center;
}
```

html

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_3_of_3">
    <h2><a href="index.html">WILL RYAN</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems it is just a matter of copying assets folder in responsive folder

Comment: Believe me, I thought that must've been the issue too since everything else seemed right. But I've checked several times and I have my asset folder on the root folder of my site, and the webfonts folder in that.

http://imgur.com/72idozv

Comment: so you got the prob  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your CSS is in here: http://willryan.us/responsive/css/ , more exactly
  [styles.css](http://willryan.us/responsive/css/styles.css)
- From there, you're trying to load `assets/webfonts/aCertainWebFont.woff`
- So the WOFF file should be in the directory `/responsive/css/assets/webfonts/`
  (*on the FTP/SSH side, something like `/var/site102/www/responsive/css/assets/webfonts/` but I digress*)

You can check in Firebug or Inspector or any Devtools (**<kbd>F12</kbd>**) in the Network tab: red color and 404 status is bad, properly loading is better :)

Comment: Oh man do I feel stupid... I wasn't realizing that my css was in a folder and not on the same level as the assets folder.

I ended up just putting a "../" in front of assets to go up a level. Thanks for the help!